# Laravel - nested routes without using a sub ID

Tags: rest, controller, routes, laravel

I'm creating a REST API in Laravel and there is one thing I can't figure out. The situation is as follows; a user can log in, browse articles and make them a favorite.

The favorite table consists out of `article_id` and `user_id`

The requests are designed in the following way:

- `[GET]` **/article/24** *view article 24*
- `[GET]` **/article/24/favorite** *indicates a favorite, if not return 404*
- `[POST]` **/article/24/favorite** *make favorite*
- `[DELETE]` **/article/24/favorite** *remove favorite*

Seems fine, but the nested resources by default expect the following format:

`/controller/[id]/sub_controller/[sub_id]`

What's the best way to avoid this *sub id* requirement? I don't need the ID of the favorite because the combination of *article id* and *user id* are enough to locate the item in my database.

These are my current routes for the requests:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController', 
  array('only' => array('index','store','show','destroy')));

Route::resource('articles.favorite', 'ArticlesFavoriteController', 
  array('only' => array('show','store','destroy')));
```

Currently, I require the API user to append /0 to the url in order to trigger the right route, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider not using Laravel's `ResourceController` here. Maybe you should go with [RestfullControllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) for your specific needs.